# Find a basis for the polynomial space where $f(1)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Choose a basis of the vector subspace and extend it to a basis.  State dimensions of the vector subspace and the vector space.
>
> $c)$ $W = \{f(x) \mid f(x) \text{ is a polynomial, degree of f is } \le 3 \text{ and } f(1)=0\}$

Here is what I've figured out so far:

The vector space is $V = \{f(x) \mid f(x) \text{ is a polynomial, degree of f is } \le 3\} = P_3$ and it has dimension $n+1=4$.

I'm given that if $f(x) = a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1$ then $f(1) = a_1+b_1+c_1+d_1=0$

Anyone know how to answer this or at least get it started?

Comment: I have :
a1x^3 + b1x^2 + c1x + d1 = 0,

f(1) = a1+b1+c1+d1=0,

dim(P3)=n+1=4

Comment: I've edited your comment into the question.  In the future, try to [format your own questions with MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make them easier to read and add any work you've already done on the problem even if it's just minor stuff.  That will increase your chances of someone answering your question.

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66862/find-a-basis-for-the-space-of-cubic-polynomials-p-such-that-p3-0) a question that's essentially the same as yours.

Comment: Forget that it's a polynomial and write it as $(a,b,c,d)$ with $a+b+c+d=0$. Can you find it now?

Answer (score 1):

You can note that $f(x) = a_1x^3 + b_1x^2 + c_1x + d_1$ then $f(1) = a_1+b_1+c_1+d_1=0$ therefore $ f(x)=a_1(x^3-1)+b_1(x^2-1)+c_1(x-1)$ and a basis is given from

$$x^3-1 ,x^2-1 ,x-1$$

Comment: $\{x-1, (x-1)^2, (x-1)^3\}$ could also be a basis.